# Regex matching too much

Tags: c#, regex

```
(\[(c|C)=)(#?([a-fA-F0-9]{1,2}){3})\](.*)\[/(c|C)\]
```

I want this expression to match text like: "This is [c=FFFFFF]white text[/c] and [C=#000]black text[/C]."

It do match one BB-code alone, but if there are more after each other (like in the example), it will create a match (1 match) of both BB-code-sequences. (from [c=FFFFFF]wh... to ...ck text[/C])

Why is this happening? Also, how do I make the dot (.) include newlines in C#?

Comment: What do you want to match "FFFFFF and #000" or do you want "FFFFFF white test and #000 black text"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about nested tags, you can do that :

```
(\[[cC]=)(#?([a-fA-F0-9]{3}){1,2})\](.*?)\[/[cC]\]
//                                     ^- lazy match
```

If you want to handle nested tags with regex, check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Nested_RegEx_explained.aspx) on code project.

Answer (score 2):

Dot matches newline characters if you set the option `RegexOptions.Singleline` ([more on that here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the RE is [greedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification); it will always try to produce the largest possible match.

It should be possible to make your RE engine non-greedy, see the linked document for tips on what to try.

Answer (score 0):

You need a lazy regular expression to not pick up all of the [c] tags

Try this

```
\[c=(#?.*?)\](.*?)\[/c\] or
\[c=(#?\w*?)\](\w*?)\[/c\]
```

You should set the options on your regex object to ingnore case.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a quick an dirty way to do this, and the solution here is to use `.*?` rather than just `.*`.  However, if you want a more robust solution is probably easier without regex.  In C# you happen to be *able* to do nested structures, but that doesn't mean it's actually easy.  It would be better to use a lexical parser and construct a DOM.  Most likely the code will be easier to read and maintain.