# Return Group From Regex, not the whole line

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex matching too much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373966/regex-matching-too-much)

Test String:

```
[TA:1010100][FN:AmplifySignal][IP:(Factor|System.Double|"1.5")(Source|System.String|"Sourcetest")(Destination|System.String|"DestTest")]
```

The general format of this string comes in 3 groups:

- group1 => "[TA:" + 1 or 0  repeated + "]"
- group2 => "[FN:" + A-Z or a-z + "]"
- group3 => "[IP:" + (.*) + "]"

I have tried many variations of a regex and can either get the whole test string to return or nothing... I can figure out how to actually segment it and return just substrings.

Attempted Patterns including but certainly not limited to:

- `@"^.*$"`
- `@"^[.*].*$"`
- `@"^(\[.*\])(.*)$"`
- `@"^(\[.*\])(\[.*\])(\[.*\])$"`
- `@"^(\[TA{[10],}\])(\[.*\])(\[.*\])$"`
  ... etc.

calling code:

```cs
BindingList<Tuple<bool[], IFactory>> Recipe = new BindingList<Tuple<bool[], IFactory>>();

var amp = new Factory.AmplifySignal();
amp.Destination = "DestTest";
amp.Source = "Sourcetest";
amp.Factor = 1.5;
bool[] Ts = new bool[] { true, false, true, false, true, false, false };

var CI = new CompactInstruction(Ts, amp.GetFactoryKey(), amp.GetProperties());

string TestString = CI.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(TestString);

string pattern = @"^(\[.*\])?"; //Have been adjusting in debug mode
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        Match Result = Regex.Match(TestString, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (Result.Success)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Result.Groups.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("G{0} - \r\n\t{1}", i, Result.Groups[i]);                            
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you apply 3 regular expressions? What does a combined, super complex one give you?

Comment: ah crap, of course the next link I follow answers my question... I needed to lazy search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373966/regex-matching-too-much

Answer (score 0):

test

```
[TA:1010100][FN:AmplifySignal][IP:(Factor|System.Double|"1.5")(Source|System.String|"Sourcetest")(Destination|System.String|"DestTest")]
```

pattern

```
string pattern = @"^(\[.*?\])?(\[.*?\])?(\[.*?\])?$";
```

Output:

```
G0 - 
    [TA:1010100][FN:AmplifySignal][IP:(Factor|System.Double|"1.5")(Source|System.String|"Sourcetest")(Destination|System.String|"DestTest")]
G1 - 
    [TA:1010100]
G2 - 
    [FN:AmplifySignal]
G3 - 
    [IP:(Factor|System.Double|"1.5")(Source|System.String|"Sourcetest")(Destination|System.String|"DestTest")]
```